# T-SQL condition on multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to modify the following clause in a T-SQL query to match this condition:

If a valid record exists in the payment table, return true, otherwise, return false

***- or -***

If the `IsPromoted` column is true, return true.

```
   CASE
     WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
           FROM   dbo.Payments
           WHERE  ( EventId = dbo.Events.EventCode )
              AND ( DATEADD(day, DurationDays, PaymentReceived) 
                                                  > GETDATE() )) > 0 THEN 'true'
     WHEN ispromoted = 1 THEN 'true'
     ELSE 'false'
   END AS UpgradedState
```

Could anybody suggest a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You should probably be doing a left join instead of this Count > 0, but I can't tell for sure until you include your entire query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `EXISTS(SELECT ...)` instead of `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...) > 0` :

```
CASE 
    WHEN IsPromoted = 1 THEN 'true' -- See Martin Smith's comment
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM .... dbo.Payments ...) THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
END
```

If the performance is very important then I would **test** solution:

1) I would create a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Payments
ADD ColumnA AS DATEADD(day, DurationDays, PaymentReceived);
GO
```

2) and I would [create an index on this computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT  OFF;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ INDEX IX_Payments_EventId_ColumnA
ON dbo.Payments(EventId, ColumnA);
GO
```

3) I would rewrite the EXISTS thus:

```
  CASE
     WHEN IsPromoted = 1 THEN 'true' -- See Martin Smith's comment
     WHEN EXITS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Payments
           WHERE EventId = dbo.Events.EventCode
           AND ColumnA > GETDATE()) THEN 'true'
     ELSE 'false'
  END
```

Also, I would try the following index:

```
CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ INDEX IX_Payments_EventId_#_DurationDays_PaymentReceived
ON dbo.Payments(EventId)
INCLUDE(DurationDays, PaymentReceived);
GO
```

Comment: +1 Should probably have the `isPromoted` check first though as this is cheaper to check. And the subquery will then be under a [pass through predicate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/23/715306.aspx)

Comment: Though testing that idea it only makes any difference if the semi join for the `EXISTS` is being implemented as nested loops I think.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that nested query is not very fast. If you want to improve performance then LEFT JOIN with dbo.Payments p on EventId = p.EventCode will work faster. Following CASE statement should do it.

```
 CASE
 WHEN (DATEADD(day, p.DurationDays, p.PaymentReceived) > GETDATE() ) > 0 THEN 'true'
 WHEN ispromoted = 1 THEN 'true'
 ELSE 'false'
```